# Creating a circle with a rounded gap

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, shapes

So I am trying to replicate the circle in this photo on illustrator over here:[image]

But unfortunately I cant seem to 'rounden' the edges of the circle. Here is my failed attempt[image]

As you can see, my attempt at one of the edges is not smooth enough. Is there any easy way I can do this on Illustrator? Thanks

Comment: What did you do in your attempt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a **line** instead of a shape, lines can have round ends.

[Relevant Adobe Help Document](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/stroke-object.html)

[image]

Comment: When I use a line, I try the stylize and rounded edges option. But the circle becomes very skewed the more I try to round it out

Comment: Have you tried the stroke panel? This is very, very basic Illustrator/googling.

Comment: Oh wow, that was a simple fix. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes, you should try googling your question first the next time.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that